# ElasticSearch group by and aggregate

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

I have a bunch of network traffic logs in ES and want to get some high level stats for each source:dest pair.

In SQL, I’d do something like:

```
SELECT src, dst, SUM(bytes)
FROM net_traffic
WHERE start>1518585000000
AND end<1518585300000
GROUP BY src, dst
```

(*start* and *end* are just epoch times during which the traffic was seen)

How can I extract the same information from the data stored in ES?

I’m coding the solution in Ruby but ideally just want an ES query to pull out the data - so solution is hopefully agnostic of implementation language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElasticSearch supports sub aggregations. You must use from that and then in your application side convert result of query to what you want.

Query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "src_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "src"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "dst_agg": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "dst"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of result:

```
{
    "key": "X1",
    "doc_count": 5,
    "agg2": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "Y1",
            "doc_count": 2 // ***
        },
        {
            "key": "Y2",
            "doc_count": 3  // ***
        }]
    }
}
```

You can extract desired data from *** in result:

```
(X1, Y1) = 2, (X1, Y2) = 3
```